# How to fill np.nan values with data from another row based on matching

Tags: python, pandas

i need to do the following

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5]
c=[0,100,100,200,200,0]
b=['2013-06-10', np.nan, '2013-02-15', np.nan, '2013-05-15']
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':a,'b':b,'c':c})
```

this will give:

```
   a           b    c
0  1  2013-06-10  100
1  2         NaN  100
2  3  2013-02-15  200
3  4         NaN  200
4  5  2013-05-15  100
```

i want to based on value in column C, lookup same value in previous row and fill the date in column B when its null.
it should eventually look like this: -

```
   a           b    c
0  1  2013-06-10  100
1  2  2013-06-10  100
2  3  2013-02-15  200
3  4  2013-02-15  200
4  5  2013-05-15  100
```

i currently do it with an apply lambda row-wise function to fill the date, but because my raw data has million of rows, it slows down tremendously. I am wondering if anyone know a much faster way to fillna values with data from a different row based on same value in column C

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can can use [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html):

```
df['b'] = df.groupby('c')['b'].ffill()
print (df)
   a           b    c
0  1  2013-06-10  100
1  2  2013-06-10  100
2  3  2013-02-15  200
3  4  2013-02-15  200
4  5  2013-05-15  100
```

Also if some first value by group is `NaN` in `b` use `apply`, becasue need apply both functions per groups:

```
print (df)
   a           b    c
0  1         NaN  100 <- NaN
1  1  2013-06-10  100
2  2         NaN  100
3  3  2013-02-15  200
4  4         NaN  200
5  5  2013-05-15  100


df['b'] = df.groupby('c')['b'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill())
print (df)
   a           b    c
0  1  2013-06-10  100
1  1  2013-06-10  100
2  2  2013-06-10  100
3  3  2013-02-15  200
4  4  2013-02-15  200
5  5  2013-05-15  100
```

Comment: i was about to say it didnt work until your edit came about as i bump into that very exact scenario. Thanks, great solution

Comment: out of curiousity, i tested your solution by looking up another separate pandas dataframe with column C:B. it is substantially slower than referencing itself. Is there a reason why?

Comment: Nice question, I think because need call constructor for new column.